# When to use builder design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, builder

Is builder design pattern is the right one to create `itemBrowsePanel` object? this object needs 2 others objects `(iconBrowsePanel,textBrowsePanel)` in order to be ready to use, as follows:

```
    HTMLPanel itemBrowsePanel=new HTMLPanel("");

    HTMLPanel iconBrowsePanel=new HTMLPanel("");        

    HTMLPanel textBrowsePanel=new HTMLPanel("");

    HTMLPanel titlePanel=new HTMLPanel(titlePanelText);     

    HTMLPanel subTitlePanel=new HTMLPanel(subTitlePanelText+" "+panelName);

    textBrowsePanel.add(titlePanel);
    textBrowsePanel.add(subTitlePanel);

    itemBrowsePanel.add(iconBrowsePanel);
    itemBrowsePanel.add(textBrowsePanel);
```

if builder design pattern is the right one, is it applicable to pass arguments to any object on creation in order to construct other objects ?

Comment: Builder is used to build complex objects. Since you create all your objects as a simple one parameter constructor, the builder pattern is not really useful. However, you do have a hierarchy structure between the objects, which is ideal for the Composite Pattern, as @Ekk pointed out.

Comment: Going back to the reference where Builder was first documented in 1995, it says `Use the Builder pattern when 1) the algorithm for creating a complex object should be independent of the parts that make up the object and how they're assembled. 2) the construction process must allow different representations for the object that's constructed.`

Answer (score 1):

[Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) is better in this case because you are building an aggregated object. It also offer more flexibility, for example, it's easier to change the panel to accept 3 instead of 2 child objects.

First, you create a base class for all UI elements in your system.

```
public abstract class UIElement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected UIElement(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public abstract void Add(UIElement element);
}
```

Then you add `HTMLPanel` and override Add to do whatever you want. In this case, you want to limit its child objects to two.

```
public class HTMLPanel
    : UIElement
{
    private List<UIElement> children = new List<UIElement>();

    // constructor here

    public override void Add(UIElement element)
    {
        if (this.children.Count > 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("");
        }

        this.children.Add(element);
    }
}
```

To construct the object, it's similar or exactly the same as what you did in your question.

In the future, you might want to show labels in panels. You can achieve that easily by adding a new class.

```
public class Label
    : UIElement
{
    public override void Add(UIElement element)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Labal cannot have a child element.");
    }
}
```

And you can just add it to the panel.

```
HTMLPanel subTitlePanel = new HTMLPanel(subTitlePanelText+" "+panelName);

Label yourLabelObject = new Label("myLabel");
textBrowsePanel.add(yourLabelObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

> this object needs 2 others objects (`iconBrowsePanel`, `textBrowsePanel`) in order to be ready to use

1. If you want to ensure that `iconBrowsePanel` and `textBrowsePanel` are added to `itemBrowsePanel` before it is used, then it is better to create an `ItemBrowsePanel` class with a specific constructor which takes these parameters and ensures the invariant

> Is builder design pattern is the right one to create itemBrowsePanel object?

2. If you want to reuse the existing construction algorithm elsewhere, it is better to wrap in into a method which takes parameters like `titlePanelText`, `subTitlePanelText` or `panelName` and returns a fully constructed `HTMLPanel`, which represents an `itemBrowsePanel`
3. If there are too many parameters and / or parameter combinations to create `itemBrowsePanel`, then yes, it may be appropriate to use a builder